# Storyboard UIView background color disappears when assigned @IBDesignable custom class

Tags: xcode, swift, uistoryboard, xcode-storyboard, ibdesignable

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create class like `MyIcon` below;
2. Drag a UIView onto storyboard (background is white);
3. Set UIView's custom class to `MyIcon`; and
4. Background color disappears.

**MyIcon.swift:**

```
import UIKit
@IBDesignable class MyIcon: UIView {}
```

See storyboard screenshot below for evidence of loss of white background color:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's a missing init function in the `MyIcon` class.
`@IBDesignable` needs at least these two functions:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}
```

To make sure, you can also have a look at the crash reports in /Users/{yourusername}/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/